# How to call a directive by when there is no attrs present?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I had a directive,

```
 .directive('lbd', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          context: '=',
          dui: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'app/templates/lbd-directive.html',
   });
```

Sometimes I call this without any atttrs but I am not sure how to do that.

This is not working,

```
 <lbd class="col-xs-12 lbd" context="" dui="" ></lbd>
```

Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: have you included the directive js file in your html ?

Comment: or it could be the template url, make sure it's correct and if there is any error in the console please add it to the question .

Comment: No Hussien,There is no error in console.

Comment: **DON'T:** Tell us "it doesn't work" and leave it at that.
We can figure this out by the fact that you've asked the question in the first place. Describe what is happens and how it differs from what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way

```
.directive('lbd', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          context: '=?', // notice the ? makes this parameter optional.
          dui: '=?' // notice the ? makes this parameter optional.
      },
      templateUrl: 'app/templates/lbd-directive.html',
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it only works with two-way binding, e.g. =?, but not with one-way binding, @?

Answer (score 0):

Your directive is correct. It's only missing unclosed bracket which should throw an error in the log. code should be

```
.directive('lbd', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          context: '=',
          dui: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'app/templates/lbd-directive.html'
   }
  });
```

you could see the running code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aq5m6uyu/1/)